# Evaluating a limit $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{Q}{\pi a^3 \frac {4}{3+x}} \frac {r^x}{a^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I struggle computing a limit for my physics project. Maybe the math is too advanced or I missed something, I have no idea. Any suggestions please?

$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{Q}{\pi a^3 \frac {4}{3+x}} \frac {r^x}{a^x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(3+x)Q}{4 \pi a^3} \frac {r^x}{a^x} = ?  $

Also $r<a$ and $r,a$ are positive constants.

Comment: You have to provide more information about $Q,r,a$

Comment: Just constants, I hope.

Comment: @Leif...yes but what is their sign?..i know that may be constants

Comment: All of them are positive (maybe except $Q$, it's a charge) and $r \lt a$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is $\lim_{y\to\infty} yk^y$? (The answer depends on whether $|k|\ge 1$.) Set $y=x+3,\,k=\frac{r}{a}$.

Comment: Well, it's an infinity if the inequality is true, but I just have realized that $r \lt a$ so $k$ is going to be zero?

Answer (score 0):

Put $b=\frac{r}{a}$ so $0<b<1$.

We know that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}b^x=0 \Rightarrow\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{b^x}=+\infty$ and $b^x>0, \forall x$

So the crusial part is to compute $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}xb^x$$

We can write $xb^x$ as this:

$$xb^x=\frac{x}{\frac{1}{b^x}}$$

This is a form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so you can apply L'Hospital's rule.
and prove that the limit is zero.

I hope this helps.